# Loop through directories and execute a command on Linux

Tags: linux, loops, unix, directory

Ex: {pwd} /home/vrm/
Say this directory has 100 directories inside it. Like dir2, dir2, dir3 and so on..

I want to go to each of these directories and execute a command (say psh make clean).

How do I do it? Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps using [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)? And most shells have `for` loops that can iterate over directories, read the manual page for your shell for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following to traverse directories

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read  -d $'\0' dname; do echo "DIR: ${dname}"; done
```

Be sure to double-quote the variable `dname`, for it may have spaces inside.

Answer (score 0):

In sh, you can use a `for` loop.  Note the `.[^.]*` to catch (most) "dot" directories.

```
for i in .[^.]*/. */. ; do
 (cd "$i"; pwd)
done
```

It'll fail on directories named "..foo", or something.  I suppose one could add `..?*`.  I haven't tried that.